# WMTS Grid Streaming using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wmts, stream

I've got a WMTS service that work well, but I would like to display a grid in qgis over it with X, Y, Z information how may I do that ?

If QGis can't generate it for us, how may I generate this kind of grid ?

---

My problem is that I would need very high zoom (17/ 18) and the generation of geopackage is impossible (30 000 000 000 000 polygon is way to much with today PC...).

Is there a way to have some kind of "stream" of grid for this level f zoom ?

Like this: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/canvas-tiles.html

Answer (score 2):

**Use [create grid tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html?highlight=create%20grid#create-grid) to create a grid.**

Note that the default for this tool is to create a temporary layer, which will be deleted when you close the project. Be sure to choose an actual file location if you want to use the grid again later.

**Label the grid with the desired information.** See the ["Label Properties" section of the QGIS manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#labels-properties) for documentation on how to display labels.

If you want to display the x, y and z coordinates of the the centroid of each grid (assuming you created a polygon grid), use the expression builder with this expression:

```
concat(x( centroid(  $geometry )), ', ' ,y( centroid(  $geometry )) , ', ' , z( centroid(  $geometry )))
```

which will display as `x, y, z` (with actual coordinate values instead of the letters)

If you want to display other information, see the ["Expression String Builder"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html?highlight=expression%20builder#the-expression-string-builder) section of the QGIS manual.

Comment: Thank you very much !
That was exactly what I needed for lower zoom (but I did not mention that...), I update my question.